# Why I get "cannot change access modifiers" when creating a custom MediaTypeFormatter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mediatypeformatter

I was trying to create a custom `MediaTypeFormatter`.

But when compiling, it reports this error:

```
cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'public' inherited member 
'System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter.CanReadType(System.Type)
```

How can I create one without overriding `CanReadType` `CanWriteType`, `ReadFromStreamAsync`, and `WriteToStreamAsync`?

Answer (score 0):

[`CanReadType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.mediatypeformatter.canreadtype%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) and [`CanWriteType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.mediatypeformatter.canwritetype%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) are abstract methods so you must override them in order to create a custom media type formatter. Just make sure not change the access modifier which is public when overriding them as the error message is telling you. You probably made them `protected` or something else:

```
public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```